# I have below code and it reads about 55 frames and then cap.read() function returns false value

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am using vs 2010 with opencv version of 2.4.9.while running the program as shown below it reads about 55 frames from the video and then it suddenly stops by giving message that 

"cannot read  frame" because the cap.read(frame) function return zero
does any body know how to solve it. 
the program is

```
int main(int, char**)
{
VideoCapture cap("C:\\test.avi"); 
if( ! cap.isOpened () )  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;


 double frnb ( cap.get ( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) );
 std::cout << "frame count = " << frnb << endl;

 double frmrate ( cap.get ( CV_CAP_PROP_FPS ) );
 std::cout << "frame rate = " << frmrate << endl;



double fIdx=1;
String str="Frame";
for(;;) {
  Mat frame;
  if ( fIdx < 0 || fIdx >= frnb ) break;
  std::cout <<fIdx<<endl;//"    ";
  cap.set ( CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , fIdx );
  fIdx=fIdx+frmrate*3;
  bool success = cap.read(frame); 
  if ( ! success ) {
  cout << "Cannot read  frame " << endl;
  break;
  }


}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your `for` loop with following. I have simplified it.
Please note

1) Don't use calculate idx etc, set and read unless you need to read random frame. For linear frame read, operator `>>` is good enough.

2) Don't rely on the frame count that you `get` from `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`, if the video or its indexing have some problem, then it is likely cause problem. It is better to check if a frame is empty every-time.

```
cv::Mat frame;  
for (;;)
{
    video >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        break;
    }

    //do whatever with frame OR uncomment following line to display frame as video
    //cv::imshow("Win_Name", frame); cv::waitKey(25);
}
```

Let me know in case of any problem or for further help. Happy Coding :)